# jquery printElement alternative css every other table row

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using the jquery printElement plug in to print the contents of a div.
I'm using an alternative css file when printing.

```
  $("#mwsAll").printElement({
  pageTitle: 'Microbiology Worksheet',
  printMode: 'popup',
        overrideElementCSS:[
            httpsBase+'/css/mwsws.css'
        ]   
  });
```

In the div "mwsAll" I have 3 tables. I want every odd table row to have a background color.
I have tried adding to all tables:

```
table tr:nth-child(odd){
background:#ccc;
```

}

and to individual tables like so:

```
#mwsTable1 tr:nth-child(odd){
background:#ccc;
}
```

but still can't get every other row to have a background color.
Other CSS elements in the file are working when printing.

What am I doing wrong?

added: tried to add full HTML but it wouldn't post.
It can be found:
[here](http://www.nbson.com/shawnstuff/test.txt)

Comment: That should work.. do you mind posting your HTML?

Comment: added link to code sample. Sorry it's largely generated and kind of a lot

Comment: Based on the HTML you just posted, it does work: http://jsfiddle.net/shVN4/ .. i'm guessing there is some other CSS interfering with it.

Comment: What's different than in jsfiddle is that the css is called from the printElement plugin. Normal styling of the form works as expected. I guess I don't really know how printElement works.

Comment: Do you *need* to call the CSS through the plugin? I'm not familiar with the plugin, but wouldn't it be easier just to include the CSS in the stylesheet..?

Comment: Do backgrounds print at all? Many browsers have settings to switch the printing of backgrounds on and off.

Comment: Also, what does `name="mComplete" '=""` mean in your HTML? This confuses jsFiddle a lot.

Comment: well that would be a bug :) Also, background images don't print by default but colors usually do. I call a separate css because it needs to look differently when printed as opposed to when displayed on the page. I think that printElement creates a new DIV and copies the components to it. The other thing I noticed is that I have checkboxes and their values are not transferred (checked on/off). I may go another route.

Comment: I could never get printElement to display how I wanted so I ended up re-rendering the sheet on the server-side for printing. thanks